# Integrating Javascript Libraries with Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, web, twitch

Just starting to learn web programming (taking class CS 253 on Udacity).

My question is how does integrating JS and google app engine work? I know this is may be a fundamental question about web programming, but I really need some guidance on how to understand this concept.

I am trying to incorporate the Twitch Javascript API into Google App Engine. Basically, I would like to have a small website where users can login via Twitch and it stores their info into a database. I really do not understand how this is possible, since Twitch only has a Javascript API.

Here is the script that I have that works perfectly for connecting to Twitch (from the examples on their git page):

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TwitchTV SDK Example App</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ttv-api.s3.amazonaws.com/twitch.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    window.CLIENT_ID = '';
    $(function() {
      // Initialize. If we are already logged in, there is no
      // need for the connect button
      Twitch.init({clientId: CLIENT_ID}, function(error, status) {
        if (status.authenticated) {
          // we're logged in :)
          $('.status input').val('Logged in! Allowed scope: ' + status.scope);
          // Show the data for logged-in users
          $('.authenticated').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
          $('.status input').val('Not Logged in! Better connect with Twitch!');
          // Show the twitch connect button
          $('.authenticate').removeClass('hidden');
        }
      });


      $('.twitch-connect').click(function() {
        Twitch.login({
          scope: ['user_read', 'channel_read']
        });
      })

      $('#logout button').click(function() {
        Twitch.logout();

        // Reload page and reset url hash. You shouldn't
        // need to do this.
        window.location = window.location.pathname
      })

      $('#get-name button').click(function() {
        Twitch.api({method: 'user'}, function(error, user) {
          $('#get-name input').val(user.display_name);
        });
      })

      $('#get-stream-key button').click(function() {
        Twitch.api({method: 'channel'}, function(error, channel) {
          $('#get-stream-key input').val(channel.stream_key);
        });
      })

    });
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>TwitchTV SDK Example App</h1>
    <div class="status">
      Status: <input readonly="readonly" size="60" val="Unknown"/>
    </div>
    <div class="authenticate hidden">
      <img src="http://ttv-api.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/connect_dark.png" class="twitch-connect" href="#" />
    </div>

    <h2 class="authenticated hidden">Authenticated</h2>
    <div class="authenticated hidden">
      <div id="logout">
        <button>Log Out</button>
      </div>

      <div id="get-name">
        <button>Get TwitchTV Name</button>
        <input readonly="readonly" size="50" value="Unknown"/>
      </div>

      <div id="get-stream-key">
        <button>Get TwitchTV Stream Key</button>
        <input readonly="readonly" size="50" value="Unknown"/>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I communicate data between this client side javascript and Google App Engine? Thanks!

Comment: What is the question exactly? How to send data generated by a JavaScript library on client side to the App Engine on server side?

Comment: Yes exactly. How does that communication work? I understand basic communication between GET and POSTS, but I just don't see how this will play out exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very broad question. But in general, regarding your case:

- You should set up a receiving end (handler) on your App Engine application. It will handle the requests from your client side JavaScript ([Hello, world](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp) example)
- Second, you will need to actually send the data to the server. I see that you're using jQuery. In order to call the server we've seen in the *Hello, world* example, you'll write something like this: `$.get('/', function(data) {console.log(data);})`. This will call the server and print to the console the message you got from the server.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made me realize that it all comes down to POST and GET requests. Just need to organize it well and I should be good.